# Cannot access postgres locally containr via airflow

Tags: postgresql, docker, connection, airflow, port

I'm trying to connect Postgres via airflow but I'm getting an error:
here is my Postgres dag:

```
"""default_args = {
'owner':'airflow',
'email_on_failure': True,
'email': 'rachelibs12@gmail.com',
'retries': 1
```

}

with DAG(
'stocks_data_example_pipeline',
start_date= datetime(2021, 10, 11),
schedule_interval='*/1 * * * *',
default_args= default_args,
catchup= False
) as dag:

```
create_stocks_table = PostgresOperator(
   task_id='create_stocks_table',
   postgres_conn_id='postgres_default',
   sql= """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stocks (  
           close_price FLOAT NOT NULL,
           symbol VARCHAR NOT NULL);
      """,
)"""
```

and my connection on airflow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8Re5.png)

and my local Postgress running:

```
5f4a77a892da   postgres                        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes                 0.0.0.0:5003->5432/tcp, :::5003->5432/tcp
```

And the error that airflow executes:

```
[2021-10-13 13:14:12,962] {base.py:78} INFO - Using connection to: id: postgres_default. Host: localhost, Port: 5003, Schema: , Login: user, Password: ***, extra: {}
[2021-10-13 13:14:12,967] {taskinstance.py:1481} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1137, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1311, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1341, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/providers/postgres/operators/postgres.py", line 72, in execute
    self.hook.run(self.sql, self.autocommit, parameters=self.parameters)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/hooks/dbapi.py", line 177, in run
    with closing(self.get_conn()) as conn:
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/providers/postgres/hooks/postgres.py", line 113, in get_conn
    self.conn = psycopg2.connect(**conn_args)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5003?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5003?
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely have Postgres listening on other IP than Airflow.

If you are using docker to run Airflow  and if you are runing on Mac/Windows and your Postgres runs on your Host , then Docker is run on a virtual machine and you need to use real IP address of your host, rather than 127.0.0.1 - because the 127.0.0.1 will be connecting to your virtual machine, not the host where the Postgres is running.